# 「所定」と「固定」の違いは何でしょうか？

Tags: word-choice

Google translate gave be result below

> 所定 = Predetermined
>
> 固定 = Fixed

Which word is used when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 所定 is a no-adjective. 固定 is a transitive suru-verb and no-adjective.

  > 固定の金額: OK
  >   所定の金額: OK
  >   金額を固定する: OK
  >   金額を所定する: NG
- Obviously, fixation of a tangible object is 固定 but not 所定.

  > その絵は壁に固定されている。
  >   The picture is fixed to the wall.
- 所定 means "it's been already determined/established by someone", 固定 means "it won't change". A 所定のルール may be revised in the future, whereas a 固定のルール is, um, fixed.

Comment: The last line made me understood the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

所定 and 固定 have totally different meanings. The reason why the translation you have found seems confusing is partially because 所定 usually never translates into one fixed  word in English.

**固定** is easy; it's a verb or a noun (but sometimes virtually an adjective) that means "to fix", "fixing", and "fixed", in the sense "to have something not move".

**所定** is hardly used in Japanese other than the form 所定の, which roughly means "which is previously given", but I guess you wouldn't see this phrase as it is in English. Instead:

> 所定の書式 *the provided/designated format*
>   所定の時間 *the appointed/arranged time*
>   所定の手続き *the prescribed procedure*
>   所定の料金 *the fee as specified (in...)*

In other words, it tells you to see and follow the content of some provision or agreement that already exists. Thus you might translate "fixed" sometimes 所定 and sometimes 固定, but they'd be quite different settings.

Machine translation is usually unreliable with pairs like English and Japanese where many grammars and concepts don't match up.