# How is 所載 used?

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

WaniKani taught me 所載, for which it offers the meaning "published".

On [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%80%E8%BC%89) I see: *1. printed; published; noted or mentioned (in a publication)​*, but it is listed as a noun. And it definitely looks like one in Japanese, but the English "printed, published…" definitely doesn't.

How do I use 所載? I've gathered from a forum thread that it's a very uncommon and technical-sounding word, but still I'm curious how this word is a past-participle in English and a noun in Japanese. Would you say 所載の記事, "the published article"? If I just talk about a 所載, is that a "published thing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can perfectly grammatically replace it with an English snippet "which is/are published/listed/posted/put on" in its place.

> 公式サイト（に）所載の画像 *picture (provided) on the official website*
>   所載の記事についての質問 *question about an article (appeared) on [somewhere]*

Two points:

1. You can use it without any qualification like your and my second examples. In this case it's like saying in English "the people injured were...", where the "in what accident" part is retrievable from previous context. If you ask about 所載の記事 to a news company, it'll be effectively translated like "on your paper".
2. 載 (the verb 載{の}る) has a meaning "[information] is recorded on [media]", which you see has no fixed English verb available, so you have to contrive a suitable verb every time for translation.

You can certainly say it's a noun, but this word is grammatically highly defective. I have only heard in forms 所載の, ～所載だ (and obviously ～所載で). This is because it's something like a bare Chinese phrase wrapped in the Japanese grammar (others include 所定 ([「所定」と「固定」の違いは何でしょうか？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/71749/7810)) and 所轄). There are also similar words already transformed into a full noun or verb such as 所属, 所得, and 所作. You can think of them something like *alibi* ("in elsewhere") and *placebo* ("I shall please").

Answer (score 1):

'Would you say 所載の記事, "the published article"?'

→ Weblio gives an ex. "一月号－の記事" (the article (on the publication published) in the month of January).  https://bit.ly/2SVsMES

So this word is to mention that the article or the statement that is talking about is sourced to a certain publication.

'how this word is a past-participle in English and a noun in Japanese.'

→ True, just 所載 is a noun but as you can see, in most cases it's used as 所載の.  I think that's why in English it's a past-participle.